# IIS Server farms with multiple DNS

Tags: iis-10

I have a single Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10.0. I use ARR for Server Farms to have a Blue-Green deployment. What i did is create 2 website with each their own folder on disk which are blue and green. I then setted up the farm with 2 server green and blue with their own port matching the website and did the host file redirect. I created a custom HTML files in both folders and use health check to see if the redirect works and indeed it works.

then i duplicated the same principle for the second site with it's own port and it works are well. Now the problem is there is that i do not find any way to redirect a specific dns on port 80 to a specific farm.

I need to redirect site1.mycompany.com:80 to farm1 and site2.mycompany.com:80 to farm2 where are these option hidden ?

Comment: What do you mean by "DNS"? "Domain names" are not "DNS".

Comment: DNS name given to me.